# How to add text in the data attribute using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Look at my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hassaan39/0kourse6/) code:
http://jsfiddle.net/hassaan39/0kourse6/

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.pin_head {
  background: #eee;
}
.pin_head:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
  height: 0;
}
.pin_head > div {
  float: left;
  margin-left: -1px;
  border-left: 1px solid #ddd;
}
.pin_head > div strong {
  font-size: 13px;
  padding: 0 10px;
  line-height: 50px;
  display: block;
}
.pin_head > div.pin_id strong {
  line-height: 50px;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
}
.pin_head > div.pin_id {
  margin: 0;
  border-left: 0px none;
}
.pin_id {
  width: 7%;
  border-left: 0px none;
}
.pin_pro {
  width: 14%;
}
.pin_date {
  width: 7%;
}
.pin_fname {
  width: 12%;
}
.pin_lname {
  width: 12%;
}
.pin_email {
  width: 11%;
}
.pin_phone {
  width: 11%;
}
.pin_pass {
  width: 20%;
}
.pin_lists ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.pin_lists ul li {
  list-style: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.pin_lists ul li:last-child {
  border-bottom: 0px none;
}
.pin_lists ul li:nth-child(even) {
  background: #fdfbfc;
}
.pin_lists ul li:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
  height: 0;
}
.pin_lists ul li > div {
  float: left;
  margin-left: -1px;
  border-left: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding: 7px 5px;
  min-height: 77px;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  margin-bottom: -99999px;
  padding-bottom: 100004px;
}
.pin_delete {
  width: 6.7%;
}
.pin_delete a {
  display: block;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 44px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.pin_lists ul li .pin_id {
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 44px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="pin_head">
  <div class="pin_id"><strong>Order ID</strong>

  </div>
  <div class="pin_pro"><strong>Product Name</strong>

  </div>
  <div class="pin_date"><strong>Dated</strong>

  </div>
  <div class="pin_fname"><strong>First Name</strong>

  </div>
  <div class="pin_lname"><strong>Last Name</strong>

  </div>
  <div class="pin_email"><strong>Email</strong>

  </div>
  <div class="pin_phone"><strong>Phone</strong>

  </div>
  <div class="pin_pass"><strong>Password</strong>

  </div>
</div>
<div class="pin_lists">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <div class="pin_id" data-col="Order ID">654</div>
      <div class="pin_pro" data-col="Product Name">Low Voltage</div>
      <div class="pin_date" data-col="Dated">2015-08-07</div>
      <div class="pin_fname" data-col="First Name">John</div>
      <div class="pin_lname" data-col="Last Name">Tait</div>
      <div class="pin_email" data-col="Email">johnson@mail.com</div>
      <div class="pin_phone" data-col="Phone">123-456-789</div>
      <div class="pin_pass" data-col="Password">passcode</div>
      <div class="pin_delete" data-col="Change Record"><a href="#">Edit</a>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="pin_id" data-col="Order ID">654</div>
      <div class="pin_pro" data-col="Product Name">Low Voltage</div>
      <div class="pin_date" data-col="Dated">2015-08-07</div>
      <div class="pin_fname" data-col="First Name">John</div>
      <div class="pin_lname" data-col="Last Name">Tait</div>
      <div class="pin_email" data-col="Email">johnson@mail.com</div>
      <div class="pin_phone" data-col="Phone">123-456-789</div>
      <div class="pin_pass" data-col="Password">passcode</div>
      <div class="pin_delete" data-col="Change Record"><a href="#">Edit</a>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I want to add text from (pin_head > div) in (.pin_lists li) data-col, using .each() function jQuery. I am here hard coding the values.

Please assist me the good road. :)
I am new in jQuery.

Comment: Let me see if I understand you. Do You wanna get text from `css` to put it inside `data-col`?

Comment: *"I am new in jQuery."* Well, then the first thing to do is to read [the API documentation](http://api.jquery.com) beginning to end. It only takes an hour or two. Then work through some tutorials. That will lead you to the [`attr`](http://api.jquery.com/attr) function and its uses, amongst other things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you want the header of each column to be the attribute `data-col` for each cell.

You can do something like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var list = $('.pin_lists li');
  $('.pin_head div').each(function(item) {
    var _this = this;
    list.each(function(element) {
      $($(this).children()[item]).attr('data-col', $(_this).find('strong').text())
    })
  })
})
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.pin_head {
  background: #eee;
}
.pin_head:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
  height: 0;
}
.pin_head > div {
  float: left;
  margin-left: -1px;
  border-left: 1px solid #ddd;
}
.pin_head > div strong {
  font-size: 13px;
  padding: 0 10px;
  line-height: 50px;
  display: block;
}
.pin_head > div.pin_id strong {
  line-height: 50px;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
}
.pin_head > div.pin_id {
  margin: 0;
  border-left: 0px none;
}
.pin_id {
  width: 7%;
  border-left: 0px none;
}
.pin_pro {
  width: 14%;
}
.pin_date {
  width: 7%;
}
.pin_fname {
  width: 12%;
}
.pin_lname {
  width: 12%;
}
.pin_email {
  width: 11%;
}
.pin_phone {
  width: 11%;
}
.pin_pass {
  width: 20%;
}
.pin_lists ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.pin_lists ul li {
  list-style: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.pin_lists ul li:last-child {
  border-bottom: 0px none;
}
.pin_lists ul li:nth-child(even) {
  background: #fdfbfc;
}
.pin_lists ul li:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
  height: 0;
}
.pin_lists ul li > div {
  float: left;
  margin-left: -1px;
  border-left: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding: 7px 5px;
  min-height: 77px;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  margin-bottom: -99999px;
  padding-bottom: 100004px;
}
.pin_delete {
  width: 6.7%;
}
.pin_delete a {
  display: block;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 44px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.pin_lists ul li .pin_id {
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 44px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="pin_head">
  <div class="pin_id"><strong>Order ID</strong>

  </div>
  <div class="pin_pro"><strong>Product Name</strong>

  </div>
  <div class="pin_date"><strong>Dated</strong>

  </div>
  <div class="pin_fname"><strong>First Name</strong>

  </div>
  <div class="pin_lname"><strong>Last Name</strong>

  </div>
  <div class="pin_email"><strong>Email</strong>

  </div>
  <div class="pin_phone"><strong>Phone</strong>

  </div>
  <div class="pin_pass"><strong>Password</strong>

  </div>
</div>
<div class="pin_lists">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <div class="pin_id">654</div>
      <div class="pin_pro">Low Voltage</div>
      <div class="pin_date">2015-08-07</div>
      <div class="pin_fname">John</div>
      <div class="pin_lname">Tait</div>
      <div class="pin_email">johnson@mail.com</div>
      <div class="pin_phone">123-456-789</div>
      <div class="pin_pass">passcode</div>
      <div class="pin_delete"><a href="#">Edit</a>

      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="pin_id">654</div>
      <div class="pin_pro">Low Voltage</div>
      <div class="pin_date">2015-08-07</div>
      <div class="pin_fname">John</div>
      <div class="pin_lname">Tait</div>
      <div class="pin_email">johnson@mail.com</div>
      <div class="pin_phone">123-456-789</div>
      <div class="pin_pass">passcode</div>
      <div class="pin_delete"><a href="#">Edit</a>

      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for assisting me :)

Answer (score 1):

Use the following jQuery to dynamically create the `data-col` elements on your `li` based on the contents of your `pin_head` div:

```
$(".pin_lists div").each(function() {
    $(this).attr("data-col", $($(".pin_head").children()[$(this).index()]).find("strong").text());
});
```

---

**Live Demo:**

```js
$(".pin_lists div").each(function() {
    $(this).attr("data-col", $($(".pin_head").children()[$(this).index()]).find("strong").text());
});
```

```css
* {
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}
.pin_head {
    background: #eee;
}
.pin_head:after {
    content:"";
    display:block;
    clear:both;
    height:0;
}
.pin_head > div {
    float:left;
    margin-left:-1px;
    border-left: 1px solid #ddd;
}
.pin_head > div strong {
    font-size: 13px;
    padding:0 10px;
    line-height:50px;
    display:block;
}
.pin_head > div.pin_id strong {
    line-height: 50px;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
}
.pin_head > div.pin_id {
    margin:0;
    border-left:0px none;
}
.pin_id {
    width:7%;
    border-left: 0px none;
}
.pin_pro {
    width:14%;
}
.pin_date {
    width:7%;
}
.pin_fname {
    width:12%;
}
.pin_lname {
    width:12%;
}
.pin_email {
    width:11%;
}
.pin_phone {
    width:11%;
}
.pin_pass {
    width:20%;
}
.pin_lists ul {
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
.pin_lists ul li {
    list-style:none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.pin_lists ul li:last-child {
    border-bottom:0px none;
}
.pin_lists ul li:nth-child(even) {
    background: #fdfbfc;
}
.pin_lists ul li:after {
    content:"";
    display:block;
    clear:both;
    height:0;
}
.pin_lists ul li > div {
    float:left;
    margin-left:-1px;
    border-left: 1px solid #ddd;
    padding:7px 5px;
    min-height:77px;
    word-wrap:break-word;
    margin-bottom: -99999px;
    padding-bottom: 100004px;
}
.pin_delete {
    width:6.7%;
}
.pin_delete a {
    display:block;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    text-align:center;
    line-height:44px;
    font-weight:bold;
}
.pin_lists ul li .pin_id {
    font-weight:bold;
    line-height:44px;
    text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="pin_head">
    <div class="pin_id"><strong>Order ID</strong>

    </div>
    <div class="pin_pro"><strong>Product Name</strong>

    </div>
    <div class="pin_date"><strong>Dated</strong>

    </div>
    <div class="pin_fname"><strong>First Name</strong>

    </div>
    <div class="pin_lname"><strong>Last Name</strong>

    </div>
    <div class="pin_email"><strong>Email</strong>

    </div>
    <div class="pin_phone"><strong>Phone</strong>

    </div>
    <div class="pin_pass"><strong>Password</strong>

    </div>
</div>
<div class="pin_lists">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <div class="pin_id">654</div>
            <div class="pin_pro">Low Voltage</div>
            <div class="pin_date">2015-08-07</div>
            <div class="pin_fname">John</div>
            <div class="pin_lname">Tait</div>
            <div class="pin_email">johnson@mail.com</div>
            <div class="pin_phone">123-456-789</div>
            <div class="pin_pass">passcode</div>
            <div class="pin_delete"><a href="#">Edit</a>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="pin_id">654</div>
            <div class="pin_pro">Low Voltage</div>
            <div class="pin_date">2015-08-07</div>
            <div class="pin_fname">John</div>
            <div class="pin_lname">Tait</div>
            <div class="pin_email">johnson@mail.com</div>
            <div class="pin_phone">123-456-789</div>
            <div class="pin_pass">passcode</div>
            <div class="pin_delete"><a href="#">Edit</a>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

---

**That live demo produces this result:**

[image: DOM]

Answer (score 0):

In jQuery you can do something like this:

```
$("#yourElement").data("yourKeyName", "yourValue")
```

For additional information you can visit [this site](https://api.jquery.com/data/) of the documentation

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this

```
 var array = [];
 $('.pin_head > div').each(function(index, obj) {
   array[index] = $(this).text();
 });

 $('li>div').each(function(index, obj) {
   var data = $(this).attr("data-col", array[index]);
 });
```